# Why is Workflow sending Emails even when Status is Complete and %Complete = 100%?

Tags: 2007, workflow, email, task-list

We have a user that is receiving the **Task assigned to** emails about once a week. He is listed in the CC field of the emails (I think this indicates he created the list entry for which the Workflow is associated).  He forwarded 2 of these emails to me, the first of which refers to a list entry that has been deleted while the other refers to a list entry that has *Status*="Complete",  *% Complete*=100% and having a *Due Date* of 8/30/2012.  The task list item corresponding to the non-deleted item (email #2) does not appear to have been marked as Approved or Rejected yet, so I initially thought this is why the email was being sent out, but this can't be the case because I took a look at the list and there are a lot more items that fall under this scenario of not being approved nor rejected and *Status*="Complete" &  *% Complete*=100%.  I asked him and he said he was not receiving emails for the other list times that are not marked as being approved nor rejected and *Status*="Complete" &  *% Complete*=100%.

Why is he receiving emails for a task item that no longer appears in the list (i.e. deleted)?

Why is he receiving emails for a task item even when *Status*="Complete" &  *% Complete*=100%???

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you positive these are 'task assigned to' emails? Is it possible there's a custom workflow also attached to this list that has some unpredictable logic causing this? Just a thought.

Comment: the 'task assigned to' is the subject of the email.  The user complaining is in the CC field (i.e., the task isn't assigned to him).

Comment: I agree this sounds like a custom workflow running on the list especially if he is listed in the CC field of the email. Typical Sharepoint notifications for task lists and alerts don't contain any references for CC. Check the site for workflows in Sharepoint Designer. It sounds as if someone might have wired up a weekly digest type email workflow.

Comment: I verified that no custom workflow is being used on this task list.  It's the Out-of-the-box Approval workflow.  The user is set up to be CC'd in the Notify Others section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer - *they're coming from our Test SharePoint farm*!

This [Microsoft forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/0dcbdd8b-8d03-4560-bd0a-c034039fa88a) helped me find it.  Other folks experienced that the Test SharePoint farm still sends out the emails pointing to Production if a backup & restore had recently been performed.

I am currently going into **Site Content and Structure**, deleting all Active Tasks so the workflows will stop sending out emails.